# Turbo Mono repo dploying a nextjs 14 to Azure App Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, next.js13, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm having a issue building and deploying a NextJS14 app to Azure App Service in my Turbo Mono Repo and I seek help understanding the correct way to do that. I tried numerous things and everytime I'm missing a dependencie or the node_module is too big and the deployment fails. So can any of you give me the correct sequence to do in my YAML to build from a mono repo and send it to my azure web app so it can run.

What I tried is since I can't send the App itself only, since building it creates weird simplink in the node_module to the root node_module, I decided to add a .npmrc with the node-linker=hoisted
symlink=false inside and the I do my pnpm install and copy the root node_module in my project then send that to the azure web app. Right now the bundle is around 500MB zipped and fails around the 40 minutes mark to send it to my machine (B1 Linux Service Plan). So I'm kind of a lost n the way to do it from a mono repo.

Just remember I'm no expert and just started this journey.

Thank you for the help

My yml scripts

azure-pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - apps/frontend/*

variables:
  - name: projectRoot
    value: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/frontend

stages:

  - stage: IdentifyAndSetVariables
    displayName: 'Identify Changes and Set Variables'
    jobs:
      - job: IdentifyChanges
        displayName: 'Identify Changes'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            submodules: true
            fetchDepth: 2
          - bash: |
              echo "Identifying modified projects..."
              MODIFIED_PROJECTS=$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1 -- apps/frontend | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | sort -u | tr '\n' ';')
              echo "Modified projects: $MODIFIED_PROJECTS"
              # -- Only for testing 
              MODIFIED_PROJECTS='transfert-passages' 
              IFS=';' read -r -a projectArray <<< "$MODIFIED_PROJECTS"
              for project in "${projectArray[@]}"
              do
                projectName=${project}
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${projectName}Changed;isOutput=true]true"
              done
            displayName: 'Get the modified projects'
            name: IdentifyChangesOutput
            env:
              SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)

  - stage: Build
    displayName: 'Build Projects'
    dependsOn: [Prepare, IdentifyAndSetVariables]
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - job: DeployInfoSecur
        condition: eq(stageDependencies.IdentifyAndSetVariables.IdentifyChanges.outputs['IdentifyChangesOutput.info-securChanged'], 'true')
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - template: info-secur-build-deploy.yml

      - job: DeployGestionAdresses
        condition: eq(stageDependencies.IdentifyAndSetVariables.IdentifyChanges.outputs['IdentifyChangesOutput.gestion-adressesChanged'], 'true')
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - script: echo "Deploying Gestion-Adresses..."
          - template: gestion-adresses-build-deploy.yml

      - job: DeployTransfertPassages
        condition: eq(stageDependencies.IdentifyAndSetVariables.IdentifyChanges.outputs['IdentifyChangesOutput.transfert-passagesChanged'], 'true')
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - template: transfert-passages-build-deploy.yml
      - job: DeployGestionDemandes
        condition: eq(stageDependencies.IdentifyAndSetVariables.IdentifyChanges.outputs['IdentifyChangesOutput.gestion-demandesChanged'], 'true')
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - template: transfert-passages-build-deploy.yml
```

transfert-passage-build-deploy.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: projectName
    type: string
    default: 'transfert-passages'
  - name: appLocation
    type: string
    default: apps/frontend/transfert-passages
  - name: azureSubscription
    type: string
    default: ''
  - name: webAppName
    type: string
    default: 'Transfert-Passages'

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '20.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  - script: |
      curl -L https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
    displayName: 'Install pnpm'
  - script: |
      echo $(TRANSFERT_PASSAGES_API_SPA) > apps/backend/nodejs/api-transfert-passages/.env
      echo $(TRANSFERT_PASSAGES_API_LOGS) >> apps/backend/nodejs/api-transfert-passages/.env
      echo "node-linker=hoisted" > .npmrc
      echo "symlink=false" >> .npmrc
      cat .npmrc
      cat apps/backend/nodejs/api-transfert-passages/.env
      pnpm install
      pnpx prisma generate --schema=apps/backend/nodejs/api-transfert-passages/prisma/schemas/cdv-sbdr021-SPA.prisma
      pnpx prisma generate --schema=apps/backend/nodejs/api-transfert-passages/prisma/schemas/cdv-sbdr015-LOGS.prisma
      pnpm run build --filter ${{ parameters.projectName }}
      mv node_modules apps/frontend/transfert-passages/
    displayName: 'Build Transfert Passages'
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: 'apps/frontend/transfert-passages'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.projectName }}.zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true
    displayName: 'Archive Build Artifacts'
  - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.projectName }}.zip
    artifact: ${{ parameters.projectName }}
```

For deployment I do it manually from the Releases menu

Comment: Are you able to build and deploy your web app successfully on your local machine?

Comment: Yes that is not a problem. I can run pnpm run build --filter <my-app> and then pnpm run start --filter <my-app> and it works. locally.

Comment: You can try to deploy your web app from your local machine using [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest). If it works, set up a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#self-hosted-agents) on your local machine and use it to run your pipeline. Ensure to use the same Azure CLI command to deploy your app in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So the way I managed to make it work in my pipeline :

1. pnpm install
2. pnpm run build --filter
3. I create a tmp file and copy over the .next from the mono repo
4. I create a simple package.json, containing the next as a dependency only, in the temp folder
5. I cd into that folder
6. run npm install
7. Then I make an artifact of that folder.
8. send it to the server

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '20.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: curl -L https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
    displayName: 'Install pnpm'

  - script: |
      export NEXT_PUBLIC_API_USERNAME=$(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_USERNAME)
      export NEXT_PUBLIC_API_PASSWORD=$(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_PASSWORD)
      export NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_AAD_APP_API_URI=$(NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_AAD_APP_API_URI)
      export NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_TOKEN=$(NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_TOKEN)
    displayName: 'Set environment variables'

  - script: |
      echo $(apiSPAConnectionString) > $(apiBackendLocation)/.env
      echo $(apiLOGSConnectionString) >> $(apiBackendLocation)/.env
    displayName: 'Set environment variables for Prisma'

  - script: |
      pnpm install
      pnpm run prisma:generate:all --filter api-$(projectName)
      pnpm run build --filter $(projectName)
    displayName: 'Build Transfert Passages'

  - script: |
      mkdir -p $(tempFolder)
      mv $(packageJSONLocation)package.json $(tempFolder)
      mv $(appLocation)/.next $(tempFolder)
      cd $(tempFolder)
      npm install
    displayName: 'Building new dependencies'
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: $(tempFolder)
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(projectName).zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true
    displayName: 'Archive Build Artifacts'
  - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(projectName).zip
    artifact: $(projectName)
```

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy Turbo repo successfully, Refer the steps below: -

My Turbo-repo app runs locally with `turbo run dev` command:-

**Commands: -**

```js
npm install turbo --global
turbo build
turbo run dev
```

**Output: -**

[image]

***My Azure DevOps pipeline code: -***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  environmentName: 'siliconwebapp655'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: npm install turbo --global
      displayName: 'Install Turbo globally'
    - script: npm install
      displayName: 'Install all packages'

    - script: |
        turbo build
      displayName: 'Build application with Turbo'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '18.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js for deployment'

          - script: npm install turbo --global
            displayName: 'Install Turbo globally'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: $(webAppName)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'SID subscription (0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: 'siliconwebapp542'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18.10'
              startUpCommand: 'turbo run dev'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***You can scale up your Web app to Standard Tier from Basic tier to increase the compute size and memory of your Web app: -***

Comment: Thank you for the answer as it's going to help me understand some of the flow but my question was more on how and what to transfert on a Web App on Azure for a NEXT JS 14 app. Building the app on my mono is not the issue. Right now I'm trying to send my .next to the web app but dependencies are always missing.

Comment: The way I manage to make it work now is by pnpm install in the mono, then pnpm run build --filter <my-app>, then create a tmp folder, copy my .next from the mono to the temp folder, create a package.json with next as a dependencie, make a npm install in that tmp folder and then send that package (tmp folder) to Azure

Comment: Okayy, Looks correct